# jQuery Mobile ui-responsive table adding extra header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery Mobile - and the new ui-responsive class for a table - the table is supposed to collapse into a single column if the viewport becomes too narrow.

However - when I drag the browser to make the viewport smaller, it takes the first column heading, and adds it to the table footer:

Viewport wide enough:

[image: Before]

Narrow Viewport:

[image: After]

My HTML markup is:

```
        <table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr class="ui-bar-b">
                <th>Column Header 1</th>
                <th>Column Header 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
                    <button data-icon="plus">Add</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

I've added a demo to jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtait/44k3E/2/

Is this just a bug in the Mobile CSS - or is it known, and is there a work around?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: this is how it should work - the headers get put above the columns for each row (showing that the data in the cell is part of that column) - you should take the add button out of the table and put it in a div as it's not part of the tabular data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not adding extra header. This is the way in which it works. It will put the heading above each column values when its width reduces.

For better understanding refer to the updated fiddle link. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/44k3E/3/)**

```
    <table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr class="ui-bar-b">
                <th>Column Header 1</th>
                <th>Column Header 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button data-icon="plus">Add</button>
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <button data-icon="plus">Add</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```